# OnReadyStateChange logic

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic withing the following function:

```
function confirm() { 
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "promote.php?user=' . $link . '";
  var params = "confirm_ref=' . urlencode(encrypt($reff,$key)) . '";
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    }
  }
  http.send(params);
}
```

As per my logic, the `http.send(params);` should be included right after the `http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200` condition. However if I do that, it doesn't work anymore.

Perhaps someone can explain how can I make sure the two conditions (readystate and status) are met before sending the post...

Comment: They aren't set by the post, they are set by the response.

Comment: What happens inside that conditional statement is what the browser does after it receives a good response back from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you assign to onreadystatechange is a callback function, which is executed when the readystatechange event is fired. This can happen at any time, so you do not block the program flow when assigning the function.

Now you want to explicitly handle the 4 - DONE state is reached. Which means that "The data transfer has been completed or something went wrong during the transfer (e.g. infinite redirects)". You also want to make sure that the status from the server is 200-OK. Both only exists after you send the request and the server returned his status code. Therefore it would make no sense to check these conditions before you send a request.